# Limsup of two sequences of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, limsup-and-liminf

Let $X_n$, $Y_n$ be two sequences of random variables. Suppose for each $n$, $X_n$ has the same distribution as $Y_n$. Can I conclude that $\limsup_n X_n$ has the same distribution as $\limsup_n Y_n?$

The reason I was thinking about this question is another question that I have in the following question. Now I summarised the key obstacle that I have.

[limsup of random variables coverges in distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565172/limsup-of-random-variables-coverges-in-distribution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $(X_n)$ to be i.i.d. copies of Bernoulli variables, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_n=-1)=1/2$. Then let $Y_0=Y_1=Y_2=\dots$ be a Bernoulli variable (let's say independant from the $X_i$).

For each $n$, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ have the same distribution. However, $\limsup{X_n}$ is $1$ almost surely while $\limsup{Y_n}=Y_0$ is a Bernoulli variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! Then if you have time, could you help me with another question that I have in the link? Thanks!